# How to create Sticky Sidebar(large content) like Myntra.com

Tags: jquery, html, css, sticky

Recently i found myntra.com and get amazed because of their dynamic Sidebar. Go to this link : http://www.myntra.com/men-casual-shoes and check out the sidebar. Normally we have found lot of Sticky items via jquery. but in case of large content in sidebar, That will not work.

But in Myntra, they did it very well. On Scroll bottom, this will stick on to bottom, on scroll top, it will stick on to top.

Was already a plugin like this available ? or How we can do like this in Jquery. ?

Comment: have you check the source code

Comment: Using JavaScript, monitor the scroll position and adjust the position of the menu accordingly.

Comment: Google jQuery sticky scroll, and for the record that site's implementation is atrocious. The page jumps around on scroll, the first stick has the top of the header in the sidebar cut off. There are FAR better examples to be looking at.

Comment: Can anyone make use of the following code i have copied from myntra http://jsfiddle.net/tM9SA/

Comment: http://web3canvas.com/item/jquery-sticky-for-long-sidebar/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For exact Myntra like menu, this might be helpful to you -
http://techbrij.com/fixed-sidebar-scrolling-jquery-div

Comment: The First Script is 90% correct. this is what i'm exactly looking. But the one problem in the script is, When we scroll up the sidebar didn't scrolling. sidebar scrolling to top only when the scrollbar reach at top. but in Myntra, The sidebar also Scrolls on ScrollUp. Hope you understand. Check myntra and your script and scroll up same time. you will find the difference...

Comment: can we do a little hack to acheive this ?

Comment: You might want to check your CSS Surjit because the demo page there seems to scroll up fine.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started using the monitor the scroll position technique:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="floatMenu">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
var name = "#floatMenu";
var menuYloc = null;

menuYloc = parseInt($("#floatMenu").css("top").substring(0, $(name).css("top").indexOf("px")))
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        offset = menuYloc + $(document).scrollTop() + "px";
        $(name).animate({ top: offset }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
    });
```

CSS:

```
#floatMenu {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
}

body {height:500px;}
```

Working example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markps/b7K9t/)

UPDATE:

Working example 2: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markps/7ey9g/95/)

Comment: Can you insert your code in to the following JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7ey9g/94/

Comment: Can anyone make use of the following code i have copied from myntra jsfiddle.net/tM9SA

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to that jquery plugin: [waypoint](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/)

Comment: Can anyone make use of the following code i have copied from myntra jsfiddle.net/tM9SA